# C# app "upload file to google drive" request returning as null

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a C# desktop app which allows the user to backup its to google drive via the google drive api V3.

I have the following method in a class which is used to load the backups

```
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
    static string ApplicationName = "MyApp";

    private static string CreateFile(string pFilePath, string parentFolderId, DriveService service)
    {

            var fileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            fileMetaData.Name = Path.GetFileName(pFilePath);
            fileMetaData.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.file";
            fileMetaData.Parents = new List<string> { parentFolderId };
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using(var stream = new FileStream(pFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetaData, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.file");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            return file.Id;
    }
```

Upon reaching `request.Upload()`, the request doesn't seem to have any issues, but later on after the `file` declaration, `file` turns out to be null, so no response body and thus no id either.

Is there something wrong with my request? I tried to see if I could catch an Exception in upload, which the method description claims would be of type `IUploadProgress.Exception`, but such an interface doesn't actually have an Exception property.

I've already authenticated and I managed to create a folder (which is the ID passed by argument parentFolderId, confirmed to not be null), so I am able to communicate with drive, just that this particular upload isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i use [How to upload a file to Google Drive with C# .net](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/) I use the async method personally

```
string uploadedFileId;
// Create a new file on Google Drive
await using (var fsSource = new FileStream(UploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
      request.Fields = "*";
      var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
         {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
         }

          // the file id of the new file we created
          uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
      }
```

As for your code i think you need execute on the end

```
request.Upload().Execute;
```

Comment: There is no .Execute property on the Upload() method, the Upload() already sends a request.
Through debugging, I managed to find out that the request is being sent, but it is sending 0 bytes and the exception BAD REQUEST is being thrown

Comment: Check the link i posted theres a youtube video at the bottom.

Comment: The problem is that the guide in question uses the async version, I cannot use `await using` with the C# version my app has.

Comment: The issue was with the mime type. I was specifying `application/vnd.google-apps.file` thinking that was just any file that goes in a gdrive, but its apparently a specific type of file. Switched it to another mime